# Entity Framework using IsOptional on primitive types when doing mappings

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a entity with the following property:

```
public int? VehicleId { get; set; }
```

I noticed when doing the mappings for it there is an *IsOptional* method provided. I asked another guy at work about whether *IsOptional* is implicit if I didn't specify *IsRequired* and I didn't really get a satisfactory answer.

He mentioned something about it depending on the *type* of the primitive, as it doesn't work with non-primitives.

Is someone able to elaborate further and let me know whether it is considered best practice to use *IsOptional* even though the property is nullable and if the above applies to all primitives?

Comment: primary key properties are always required by default, foreign key properties are also required by default. All other properties are optional (nullable). All data types mappable to db should be primitive, when you say about non-primitive you are talking about `navigation property` which is in fact not part of the db (it's part of the model).

Comment: So you use `IsOptional` explicitly usually against foreign key properties. Use `IsRequired` explicitly usually against other properties (except primary keys and foreign keys).

Comment: Are `navigation properties` equivalent to Dapper `[Write(false)]` properties? Thank you for the rule about primary and foreign keys. What about if the foreign key is nullable?

Comment: Foreign key example:

I.e. there is a _Vehicle_ table which has a foreign to a _VehicleHistory_ table. The _VehicleHistory_ table also has a foreign key to the _Vehicle_ table. To enable insertion - the _historyId_ column on the _Vehicle_ table is nullable so that we can insert a record for the vehicle, create the initial entry in _VehicleHistory_, then go back and update the _Vehicle_ table with the foreign key.

Yes I realise the the design is less than ideal but it's what I have to work with.

Comment: I don't know about `Dapper` but navigation properties can be easily understandable, it represents relationship between entity classes. You can search for more on that. When understanding about foreign key, you should associate it with kinds of relationship: ***one-one***, ***one-many***, ***many-many***. In ***one-one*** relationship, the foreign key should not be null and can be on either side. In ***one-many*** relationship, the foreign key should be on many side and can be null. In ***many-many*** relationship, the foreign keys should be in a separate table (join table) & should not be null

Comment: in your case the tables may be wrong designed, I guess the relationship between `Vehicle-VehicleHistory` here is ***many-many***, so you need a separate junction table to contain the foreign keys (whose composition can be the primary key of the junction table). Because it's wrong designed it's hard to work with it and there may some consequent result/issues to deal with in future.

Comment: Thank you for your help and detailed explanations @Hopeless. I had a feeling that there was a better way. I will look into junction tables and `navigation properties` then make a decision about how I want to try and manage the relationship.